# How do I increase the white space between a section's title and the page header?

Tags: spacing, formatting

I would like something like this: [image]

I'm using `article` document class and package `geometry`, but I think I'm missing some definitions for the sections. I'm new at this and would like to write my masters thesis on this platform. This is part of my code, what I've got so far.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{article}
% LANGUAGE AND FONTS PREAMBLE
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter}%document font type
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}%Allows clickable references
%PAGE AND TITLES FORMATTING
\usepackage[margin=2cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist %Allows to change margins in selected particular parts of the text

\titleformat{\section} %Commmands for all titles formatting
  {\Large\sc\bfseries\center}{\thesection}{0.5cm}{}
\begin{document}

\section*{ABSTRACT}\label{sec:abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}ABSTRACT}
Abstract do trabalho. Inglês, com keywords.
Work abstract, English with keyboards.

\cleardoublepage
\section{INTRODUÇÃO}\label{sec:intro}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[4]
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

Comment: please make your question more clear. add some information and a minimal example of your code.